# Populating Double Curly Braces Within $sce.trustAsHtml

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-interpolate

I have to render a string (item.tabs.review.content), that is parsed into HTML using $sce.trustAsHtml.

The main issue I am having is that within the string are references to an array in the item object (item.tabs.review.images).

```
.material(ng-bind-html='item.tabs.review.content')
```

The issue that I am having is that once the HTML is rendered in the browser, the double curly braces are being ignored and are not being populated by the object?

```
<h1>TEsting</h1>
<img ng-src='data{{item.tabs.review.images[0].filetype}};base64{{item.tabs.review.images[0].base64}}'>
```

Added a plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/Jkrx3SxNjWmHPQnKbnFY?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest create directive that will play with the value first by using `$parse`, `$parse` with a `scope` will give the value of that scope variable provided in directive attribute. And then unescape the `html` to replace the html `entity`'s to the html tags, for that you should use `unescapeHTML` function which I added an answer. Afterwards use `$interpolate` to get value of `{{}}` interpolated content will give your `src`. `$sce.parseHtml` to sanitize the html content.

**Markup**

```
.material(bind-img='item.tabs.review.content')
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('app').directive('bindImg', function($parse, $interpolate, $sce) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var parsed = $parse(attrs.bindImg)(scope)
      parsed = unescapeHTML(parsed)
      var html = $interpolate(parsed)(scope)
      element.html($sce.trustAsHtml(html));
    }
  }
})

//unescape html
function unescapeHTML(escapedHTML) {
  return escapedHTML.replace(/&lbrace;/g,'{').replace(/&rbrace;/g,'}');
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/htGUk40ZxPFLTGdBYS0D?p=preview)

Comment: did you mean "var html = $interpolate(input)($scope)"? I tried your code and everything is being filtered out. With the code above the HTML is being rendered, but the {{item.tabs.review.images[0].filetype}} is not being populated from the $scope. So far I think that ng-bind is using innerHtml to populate, and not even seeing the {{}}... Thank you for following up

Comment: @JohnSpiteri oh..you are rendering image from `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I am saving images base64 and when the database object returns - it has all of the material in one object. The use of what I am doing - A user is entering valid HTML into a textarea element, which is being saved as a string (item.tabs.review.content). In that string I am referencing images that are part of that object (item.tabs.review.images). Using ng-bind-html='item.tabs.review.content, I am only getting empty {{}} that are not being populated?

Comment: I tried your code and am still getting nothing returned. Going to make a plunkr quickly... Thank you

Comment: Your plunker works perfectly... Thank you @Pankaj Parkar, nice answer.

Comment: @JohnSpiteri glad to help you in that..Thanks :)